# Why do I get a syntax error when everything seems to be fine?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm starting with python code and when doing some exercises one of them gave me a syntax error:

```
fruit_dict= {} fruit_dict['apple'] = 10 fruit_dict['pear'] = 3 fruit_dict['walnut'] = 216
fruit_dict.keys()
```

```
File "<ipython-input-24-853fedccd771>", line 1
    fruit_dict={} fruit_dict['apple'] = 10 fruit_dict['pear'] = 3 fruit_dict['walnut'] = 216
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work, if someone can help me with this I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this because you perform all your assignments on the same line. This is not possible in python.

```
fruit_dict = {}

fruit_dict['apple'] = 10
fruit_dict['pear'] = 3
fruit_dict['walnut'] = 216

fruit_dict.keys()
```

This will work.

Comment: why the -1?  Anthony's answer is correct, and I was going to post the same.  You can't put all the fruit_dict assignments on one line like you had

Comment: I just did my part to even it up :)

Comment: Thank you!!! It did! But do you know why I got that syntax error before?

Comment: To add: simple statements can also be separated on the same line with semicolons (e.g. `x = {}; x["a"] = 1`), but the newlines are preferable.

Comment: If you look at the error, it clearly points at where in the line, the syntax is wrong